# Why is my Lumia not recognised when plugged into Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: lumia, usb

I have a Lumia 730 with WP 8.1 denim, when USB connecting it to windows 8.1 or Windows 7, it is recognised just fine, but when I use a Windows Server 2012 R2, the phone doesn't show up in file explorer.

Why would I plug it into a server? I'm traveling for awhile without a PC,I have an external SSD with Windows To Go using Server 2012 R2. I can plug this into any modern PC and boot my own Windows, rather than using the one on the hard disk. Sometimes I would like to backup photos from the phone to the SSD.

Is the anything I can configure so that the server OS recognises the phone?

I don't have any additional windows server to test whether his problem is unique to my installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically one would suggest that you need a driver, but I doubt that this is the right solution and I couldn't find one looking on Microsoft or Nokia sites either.

The [Windows Phone Recovery Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987) installs drivers, but I assume these are only for installing a new factory image not necessarily accessing mass-storage of the device the way a user is supposed to do. (I assume here that this is similar to Android.) I found a similar question for the [Nexus 4](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75937/20651), where the OP states that the Android drivers for the device were already installed and it still doesn't seem to work.

Mass-storage access for these devices is implemented with MTP which stands for [*Media* Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) and works very similar to mass-storage on cameras. Basically it should work out of the box on desktops without requiring special drivers and that's how it also works on Linux/Ubuntu. 
MTP support on Windows seems to be integrated into **Windows Media Player** according to the Wikipedia article about MTP, so you would [need to install Windows Media Player](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a816bbdc-5a9c-4cf9-aa8c-090a61da3e3a/need-to-install-windows-media-player-on-windows-server-2012-release-candidate-many-apps-requires?forum=winserver8gendesktop%20experience) through **Desktop Experience** on Windows Server.

Greg Olsen has more details and [instructions on his blog](https://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/windows-server-2012-how-to-add-desktop-experience-feature/):

> Desktop Experience enables a few handy tools like:
>
> - Windows Media Player
> - Desktop themes
> - Video for Windows (AVI support)
> - Windows SideShow
> - Windows Defender
> - Disk Cleanup
> - Sync Center
> - Sound Recorder
> - Character Map
> - Snipping Tool
>
> Steps to enable the Desktop Experience on Windows Server 2012 (Note: A restart will be required to complete install):
>
> 1. Launch Server Manager
> 2. Select Add roles and features
> 3. Within the Add Roles and Features Wizard, select Features from the left hand menu
> 4. Within the Add Roles and Features Wizard,  expand the option  User Interfaces and Infrastructure (Installed)
> 5. Select Desktop Experience
> 6. Click Add Features (on the next dialog window)
> 7. Click Next
> 8. Click Install
> 9. Click Close (When complete) Note: A restart will be required to complete install
>
> Below are the screenshots displayed during this process.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I should have thought about MTP myself. To install the desktop experience I opened an elevated Powershell and ran: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName DesktopExperience -All`, much easier than the 9 steps listed above.